# ip address search algorithm or library in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, ip

I have a network application that is making ip_address based firewalling. I find the source ip of the client in my application and then, if the ip of the client is in the subnet of the ips in my configuration file, then i deny or accept that ip.

In the configuration file, there may be different ip formats. It can be a single ip like `192.168.0.1` or a subnet `192.168.0.1/24` or an interval like `192.168.0.1-192.168.0.37`. These ip adresses are read from the configuration file and if the client ip is in one of these, then the action is taken.

It is a search of the client ip in the ips that come from conf file.There are some algorithms in python for these.But is there a C or c++ library for this job.That will parse the ips in these formats and search the client?.

Comment: you could use a Trie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie to store the addresses. You get very fast lookups, but your program may use a lot of memory. It's easy to implement it, or you can use a library that already implements it.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm struggling because all of the text is in one paragraph. Any chance you could edit and split it up a little? <totally not related to the original question, sorry>

Comment: BTW, still doing only IPv4 in 2012 ?

Comment: Will there be exact one match per ip or do you need something like longest-prefix matching?

Comment: KillianDS. I have tried to parse the ips from conf file and iterate over the / and - chars. and then find the number of the ips and write them to string array.it can be done but it is so tiresome. now i am looking for a library that can parse the ips like i want

Comment: Ottovio Campana. Problem is not storing the adresses. i am loooking for an algorithm to read from conf and store somewhere according to the subnet notation with '/' and '-'

Answer (score 1):

> is there a C or c++ library for this job?

I don't know.

But if I had to write such a library then I would use integers (32-bit for IPv4). Sorting and checking will then be much faster. And ranges can be addressed with 64-bit values.

Using strings, by comparison, would be painfully slow.

Comment: Totally agree with this. There's no real need for complex structures as an IPv4 address is just a 32 bit integer.